# C++ application failing to build with 'cannot find -lmysqlpp' but it appears to be there

Tags: c++, mysql, netbeans

I'm trying to build an application with Netbeans and getting the following error:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlpp

I believe this exists as per the below screen shots;

[image]

and here in my includes from Netbeans;

[image]

The below is the full output from Netbeans;

```
cd '/media/psf/DL/DL_src/FEC_src/docugirl'

/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug

"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf

make[1]: Entering directory '/media/psf/DL/DL_src/FEC_src/docugirl'

"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk /app/bin/docugirl

make[2]: Entering directory '/media/psf/DL/DL_src/FEC_src/docugirl'

mkdir -p /app/bin

g++     -o /app/bin/docugirl build/Debug/GNU-Linux/docugirl.o -lm -lpthread /pcli/library/libcore.a /pcli/library/libsdd.a -lmysqlpp

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlpp

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:67: /app/bin/docugirl] Error 1

make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/psf/DL/DL_src/FEC_src/docugirl'

make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: .build-conf] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/psf/DL/DL_src/FEC_src/docugirl'

make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:40: .build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 472ms)
```

For completeness, the source exists on a remote Debian server (as has previous successfully created and built mysql type applications).

So, I'm a little confused, I thought and assumed that I had the necessary mysql stuff in order to build this, I am able to build other mysql applications with this setup. Is this **mysqlpp** different/additional to the /usr/include/mysql and /usr/include/mysql++?

The **/usr/include/mysql** links to **/usr/include/mariadb**

Any help would be greatly appreciated here, thanks in advance...

Comment: The linker (`ld`) tries to find a MySQL++ library file, which is named `libmysqlpp.so`. Do you have such file in the `/usr/lib` directory?

Answer (score 0):

@HEKTO This was indeed the problem but it seemed that the current release of Debian (10.5) did not include the **libmysql++-dev** package, the reasons for which are as yet unknown to me and although I had copied the mysql++ header files across, the **libmysqlpp.so** was indeed not there. In this instance, I resorted to using a previous release, although I believe the next release will include this.

See here: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libmysql++-dev